# AsyncTask won't run multiple times even thought postexecute is called

Tags: android

I am using an `AsyncTask` in order to contact a server written in java through a socket and confirming my user/password that the android client sends.

The first time I click the sign in button it works, but the 2nd time, the async task only gets to `onPreExec()` and not any further.

I've searched this online but I only found questions why it doesn't work the first time or how to run multiple in the same time. But I don't want to run multiple `AsyncTasks` as it is not necessary.

This is how I call the `AsyncTask` :

```
new LoginAsyncTask(this, user, password).execute();
```

And this is the `LoginAsyncTask` class:

```
package com.course.chat;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ActivityLogin main;
    private String loginResult, user, password;

    public LoginAsyncTask(ActivityLogin main, String user, String password){
        super();

        Log.d("constructor", "ay ay");
        this.main = main;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("dopreexecute", "doing stuff here also");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("doinBackground", "doin my stuff");
        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket("79.119.139.180", 6969);

            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);
            ps.println(user + "," + password);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                Log.d("doinbackground", line);
                if (line.equals("OK")) {
                    loginResult = "OK";
                    break;
                }
                else if (line.equals("FAIL")) {
                    loginResult = "FAIL";
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("onPostExecute", "doing my stuff");
        if(loginResult.equals("OK"))
            Toast.makeText(main, "Signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if(loginResult.equals("FAIL"))
            Toast.makeText(main, "Invalid user or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

At first I thought it may be because it didn't finish the last one but it most certainly does because it shows me the toast with `"OK"` or `"FAIL"`.

Comment: As per your code, you didn't close the socket, InputStream and OutputStream in your finally block. Please confirm, did you get the log output  Log.d("doinBackground", "doin my stuff"); when you click second time?

Comment: I didn't get the doinbackground the 2nd time. The 2nd time it only got to 'Log.d("dopreexecute", "doing stuff here also");

Comment: You should explicitly close the socket. Is it possible the server only accepts one socket connection at a time and the first one is still open?

Comment: yes, the server accepts only one socket. I'll modify the code to close the socket before leaving and ill comment again

Comment: ok, this was the problem, the fact that i didnt close the socket and the server only accepted one

Comment: @RanjithSubramaniam please write your comment as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here, socket connection need to be closed within the finally block of the **doInBackground** method. Because the server is accepting only a socket at a time.

Also, InputStream, OutputStream and BufferReader should be closed by using finally block.

So the code should be appeared like this inside doInBackground finally block,

```
finally {
     if(socket != null)
          in.close();
          out.close();
          reader.close();
          socket.close();
}
```

Comment: ' Because the server is accepting only a socket at a time.'. That may be a fact. But this client is never coming back. And it is good client behaviour to close the used socket when done. Even if the server accepts more clients.